# Importing XML in to phpmyadmin database

Tags: mysql, xml, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import XML from this site http://data.gov.uk/dataset/car-parks to a phpmyadmin database, so I can use it in a google maps mashup.

I'm new to this and not sure how to go about getting the XML in to the database. Do I create the database columns first and then import the data?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) method in mysql, through which you can import the data from XML into your database.

An Example:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE `tablename` (fieldl1, field2, ...);
```